# unable to get the email address

Tags: android, android-contacts

This question is already asked [Getting contact email by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538195/getting-contact-email-by-name) but this is not helpful for me.I have the following code for getting email address unfortunately it is not working. anybody help to solve this.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor emailCur = cr.query( 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.Display_Name + " = ?", 
                new String[]{name}, null); 
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
                String email = emailCur.getString(
                              emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                              emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE)); 
                tv2.setText(email);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            emailCur.close();
```

and also i tried using contact_id.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
public static void getContactEmails(Context context) {
        String emailIdOfContact = null;
        int emailType = Email.TYPE_WORK;
        String contactName = null;


            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                    contactName = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    // Log.i(TAG,"....contact name....." +
                    // contactName);

                    cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                    while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                        emailIdOfContact = emails.getString(emails
                                .getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                        // Log.i(TAG,"...COntact Name ...."
                        // + contactName + "...contact Number..."
                        // + emailIdOfContact);
                        emailType = emails.getInt(emails
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));


                    }
                    emails.close();

                }
            }// end of contact name cursor
            cur.close();


    }
```

Comment: Already tried this one. my problem is while loop iteration is zero it doesn't start.

Comment: Have you add the permission to access the contact in manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: yes i added the permission. able to access the phone number but email is not accessed.

Comment: http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-code-for-reading-phone-contacts.html